# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT of a range of numbers

Tags: mysql, loops, range, group-concat

I have a table like...

```
year_from| year_to |...            
---------|---------|----
  1990   |  1993   |...     -> 1990 1991 1992 1993            
  2000   |  2004   |...     -> 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004
  2003   |  2005   |...     -> 2003 2004 2005
```

and I am trying to find out if there is a way to generate a column only with SQL in a clean way printing the rage (kind of mix between a loop and GROUP_CONCAT in nested selects), but I do not get it.
This will be for a fulltext search column index from other tables, and because I have a restricted version of MySQL (5.6), actually the performance is not critical in this issue, the priority is to keep a single sql and avoid to create any procedure.
Any comments are welcome!
& thanks in advance

Comment: The requirement seems unclear to me. What's your expected output?

Comment: the one shown after the arrow in the table abobe ;)
Given two columns, from-to filled with years (from<=to), the years between them in a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a derived table containing all available years, something like this:

```
SELECT s.year_from,s.year_to,GROUP_CONCAT(t.year_col SEPARATOR ' ') as new_col
FROM(
    SELECT 1990 as year_col UNION ALL SELECT 1991 UNION ALL SELECT 1992 ...--ALL THE YEARS HERE
    ) t
INNER JOIN YourTable s
 ON(t.year between s.year_from and s.year_to)
GROUP BY s.year_from,s.year_to
```

Which will produce :

```
year_from | year_to | new_col
  1990        1993     1990 1991 1992 1993
  ....
```

Comment: Thanks sagi !!, Even I will have to take care about all the years will be in the range of the hardcoded years (a hole century XD) , it is actually functional.

Comment: No problem:) . Instead of writing a long select for a century, make time table and just select from the table. Will be easier to maintain and read. @jalbertoa